# Best way to implement jquery scoping on object classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I would like to define objects which act as classes (having private and public methods/properties). But also having a way to define a scope to that object. To illustrate, consider this pseudocode:

```
var myclass = function(context) {
    $.setscope(context);  // <-- this is not real, but I want something like this

    this.getItems = function() {
        return $('.grid');  // after calling `setscope` above, this will look in the scope of #page1
    };
}
var myclass_instance = new myclass("#page1");
```

Basically what this does, it forces jQuery to automatically use the scope of `#page1` when ever I 'select' something from within myclass_instance. All code in it (public or private) should automatically use that scope. In other words, I shouldn't have to do `return $('#page1').find('.grid');`.

What I have now is a `var context = '#page';` defined on top, and then `$(context).find(...` everywhere in the class. This seems kinda redundant.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if not, the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
function myClass(context) {
  var _$ = $,
      $ = function() {
        return _$.find(context).apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
      };

  this.getItems = function() { return $('.grid'); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like it's pretty simple abstraction you're looking for. Just define a method on `MyClass` that always queries the dom in the scope that you set on instantiation:

```
var MyClass = function(scope) {
   this.scope = scope;
};

MyClass.prototype.get = function(selector) {
  return $(selector,this.scope);
}

MyClass.doStuff = function() {
   var $el = this.get('#someid');
   //do some stuff with $el;
}

var o = new MyClass('#scope');
```

Comment: This forces you to use a new method `get` to do selections. Can you get it to work for the `$` like in regular jquery?

Comment: Sure, but that's potentially adding a confusing layer to anybody whose not you and looks at your code later on. More importantly, what if you actually want to use `$` without the scope at some point in your class? Dangerous stuff to overwrite the default function that everybody expects `$` to be when using the jQuery library.